# Coded UI test - how to programmatically set a Select Option

Tags: c#, select, controls, coded-ui-tests

I'm writing some coded UI tests to automate testing of some webpages. I've chosen to write the code by hand rather than record a manual testing session.

I can modify controls on the page, for example an input box:

```
var edit = new HtmlEdit(browser);
edit.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlEdit.PropertyNames.Id, id);
edit.Text = value;
```

or click on a button:

```
var btn = new HtmlInputButton(browser);
btn.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlInputButton.PropertyNames.ValueAttribute, "Enter");
Mouse.Click(btn);
```

I can't work out how to set the value of a dropdown, e.g.

```
var select = new HtmlControl(browser);
select.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlControl.PropertyNames.Id, "Country");
select.????
```

the ValueAttribute is read only.

Any ideas?

Comment: Let Visual Studio show you how. Record the action into a sandbox project then copy the bits or techniques that you need.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, I may well try that if there is no quick response. HtmlComboBox might be what I need, just looking into that

Answer (score 1):

Use an `HtmlComboBox` instead. `HtmlControl` is generic and has limited properties.

```
HtmlComboBox combox = new HtmlComboBox(browser);
combox.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlControl.PropertyNames.Id, "Country");

//Select by Index
combox.SelectedIndex = 0;
//Select by ITem
combox.SelectedItem = "India";
```